# How to work with placing drawable images with appropriate sizes

Tags: android

Hello there are many articles for this question but non explain them correctly. Can somebody clearly explain me about size of image should be? and how are they to be made or xxhdpi hdpi and all? Please give me example appropriately. And everything so that it helps other people o this community

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to take an image for xxxhdpi screen (Try using sketch or photoshop to design and choose the image that fits perfect for xxxhdpi screen) and generate 9 nine patch image for it from https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example .After that go to your android project from file explorer and in 'res' directory paste the 9 patch images (the images are already in their respective file densities so no worries there).

Comment: how to make image fir xxxhdpi screen

Comment: Try using flickr for free good quality images and then insert in skecth(Mac) or Photoshop(Windows).(Read some articles on UI designing for android you would understand better)